# Restore a local Sql Server database used by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm a beginner with the use of `Entity Framework` : I have done a web application using `EF` so i created a local Sql Server database and i added a context class **EFDbContext**.

When i run the application in another machine i got this error :

`The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).`

i think it is because the local database is missing. So i need to know:

1. In a similaire case, How can i restore my database?
2. What are the differences between managing databases with `Sql Server Manager` and the `integrated connection tool` in VS ?

Comment: Do you need to use the same database from the new machine or a new database?

Comment: @Kaf i have done an application , and i need to put it in another machine .So i have to use the same database

Comment: What is your connection string? if you are using `localhost`, you have to change it to local IP address or network name of the database hosting machine. There may be other issues (according to the error message) but first you need to make sure you can connect to the database.

Comment: this is the connection string `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>`. I think you didn't understand me : i need a method like restoring the database using the backup(.bak) file so i need a copy of the database in the new machine

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a method. But if you need to create the database in the new machine, you can use Package Manager Console and run update-database command to do it.

Comment: How can use `Package Manager Console` to create the database?

Comment: (1). PM> `enable-migrations` (2). PM> `add-migration db_migrationX` (3). PM> `update-database`. Note: you may not need (1) and (2) if you have created migrations before.

Comment: Good, please put it as an answer.Thanks you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, you can create the database in the new machine using `Package Manager Console`. Please follow the following steps.

```
(1). PM> enable-migrations 
(2). PM> add-migration db_migrationX 
(3). PM> update-database.
```

Note: you may not need (1) and (2) if you have created migrations before.